# How can i select certain document variable to delete?

Tags: vb.net, openxml

Below code are remove all document variable.i want to delete certain document variable only.How do i set the condition?

```
'Remove all 
Public Sub RemoveDocVariables(ByRef fileName As Object)
    Using doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, True)
        doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.RemoveAllChildren(Of DocumentVariables)()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to iterate the collection manually

```
Public Sub RemoveDocVariables(ByRef fileName As Object)
    Using doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, True)
        For Each DV As DocumentVariables In doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.OfType(Of DocumentVariables).ToArray()
            If PlaceYourConditionHere Then doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.Remove(DV)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it